# $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Differentiablility

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

I am trying to understand the Least Absolute Deviation algorithm, which basically is

```
min l1-norm(z) 
subject to z=Ax-b
```

I want to understand how is the l1-norm not differentiable, we have a function which is a linear function, shouldn't it be once differentiable?
How is using l1 norm in the objective function more robust than using l2 morm?

Comment: Also I want to know how is using an L1 norm more robust as compared to using an L2 norm in the objective function.

Comment: The $L^1$ norm isn't a linear function.

Comment: For example, consider what happens if z is a scalar. Then the l1 norm is the absolute value $|z|$, which is not differentiable at $z=0$. More generally, for a vector, the l1 norm is not differentiable at a point $z$ whenever one or more of the components $z_i$ is zero.

Comment: "I want to understand how is the l1-norm not differentiable". This kind of question always mystifies me (and yes, questions of this type come up a lot: "why is this *not* X"). *Have you tried differentiating it*? If not, why would you assume it *is* differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

The $l-1$ norm is not differentiable, as it involves absolute values. But luckily you can cast the problem as a linear program. Firstly, you can write

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min &\sum t_i\\
s.t.&\\
& t_i \geq |z_i|,\quad i=1,\ldots\\
&z = Ax -b,\\
&t_i\geq 0,\quad i=1,\ldots,
\end{array}
$$

then you just split the absolute value in two linear inequalities:

$$
t_i\geq |z_i| \Rightarrow \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
t_i\geq z_i,\\
t_i\geq -z_i.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Thus summarizing:

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min &\sum t_i\\
s.t.&\\
&t_i\geq z_i,\\
&t_i\geq -z_i,\\
&z = Ax -b,\\
&t_i\geq 0,\quad i=1,\ldots,
\end{array}
$$

That would do.